# Trigger to insert Value on a column if?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to create a trigger on a table that updates in every insert the value of a column if a condition is present.
So in table like this:

[image]

I need the trigger to update all null values to '1' if "RegimeIva" = '3' in order to get a result like this:

[image]

I have tried:

```
create or replace TRIGGER AtualizaNat before INSERT ON Cabecdoc  
for each row
BEGIN
  if :new.IntrastatnatA is null and :new.intrastatnatB  is null and :new.regimeiva = '3' then
    :new.intrastatnatA : 1; :new.intrastatnatB : 1;
  else
    :new.intrastatnatA : null; :new.intrastatnatB : null; 
  end if;
END;
```

This is not working

Comment: `= is null` needs to be `is null` and `:= is null;`  needs to changed to `:= null;`

Comment: Yes my mistake! but this still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to update only one row being inserted? If so, what does not work exactly?

Comment: Assigning value should happen by := and not only : so it should be :new.intrastatnatA := 1; instead of :new.intrastatnatA : 1;

Comment: Yes, just the one row being inserted. "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected few syntax errors in your code.

Here's a little example. It works fine for me:

```
create table Cabecdoc (IntrastatnatA number, IntrastatnatB number, regimeiva char(1));


create or replace TRIGGER AtualizaNat before INSERT ON Cabecdoc  
for each row
BEGIN
  if :new.IntrastatnatA is null and :new.intrastatnatB  is null and :new.regimeiva = '3' then
    :new.intrastatnatA := 1; :new.intrastatnatB := 1;
  else
    :new.intrastatnatA := null; :new.intrastatnatB := null;
  end if;
END;

--inserting a row...
insert into Cabecdoc values (null, null, '3');

--...and checking
select * from Cabecdoc;


--Output:
IntrastatnatA IntrastatnatB regimeiva
1             1             3
```